# boto3 AWS Batch missing `logStreamName` in `.describe_jobs()` response

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I am trying to get the logs of an AWS Batch job using the following code

```py
import boto3

batch_client = boto3.client("batch")
batch_response = batch_client.describe_jobs(jobs=["<JOB ID HERE>"])
print(batch_response["jobs"][0]["container"]["logStreamName"])

# Fails with
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
# KeyError: 'logStreamName'
```

It used to work till yesterday but from today (roughly Sep 9, 2020, 04:55 AM IST) it isn't. All the tasks that I have created today are missing the `logStreamName` in their response.

As per https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/batch.html#Batch.Client.describe_jobs, the `logStreamName` should be present in the response.

*NOTE:* Downgrading or upgrading boto3 version seems to have no effect. Tried on the latest 1.14.57 and an older 1.13.26

**EDIT**
The logs are present on cloudwatch but not present in the response (only for the new tasks). There was a new boto3 release 12 hours ago and might be affecting? The value (redacting some stuff) for the `batch_response` is

```json
{
    "ResponseMetadata": {
        "RequestId": "string",
        "HTTPStatusCode": 200,
        "HTTPHeaders": {
            "date": "string",
            "content-type": "string",
            "content-length": "string",
            "connection": "string",
            "x-amzn-requestid": "string",
            "x-amz-apigw-id": "string",
            "x-amzn-trace-id": "string"
        },
        "RetryAttempts": 0
    },
    "jobs": [
        {
            "jobName": "string",
            "jobId": "string",
            "jobQueue": "string",
            "status": "SUCCEEDED",
            "attempts": [
                {
                    "container": {
                        "containerInstanceArn": "string",
                        "taskArn": "string",
                        "exitCode": 0,
                        "networkInterfaces": []
                    },
                    "startedAt": 1599621988773,
                    "stoppedAt": 1599624120887,
                    "statusReason": "Essential container in task exited"
                }
            ],
            "statusReason": "Essential container in task exited",
            "createdAt": 1599621980433,
            "startedAt": 1599621988773,
            "stoppedAt": 1599624120887,
            "dependsOn": [],
            "jobDefinition": "string",
            "parameters": {},
            "container": {
                "image": "string",
                "vcpus": 1,
                "memory": 8192,
                "command": [],
                "jobRoleArn": "string",
                "volumes": [
                    {
                        "host": {
                            "sourcePath": "string"
                        },
                        "name": "string"
                    }
                ],
                "environment": [
                    {
                        "name": "string",
                        "value": "string"
                    }
                ],
                "mountPoints": [
                    {
                        "containerPath": "string",
                        "sourceVolume": "string"
                    }
                ],
                "ulimits": [],
                "exitCode": 0,
                "containerInstanceArn": "string",
                "taskArn": "string",
                "networkInterfaces": [],
                "resourceRequirements": []
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Does the job log stream exist in the CloudWatch Logs? Maybe it has not been created, thus its not present in boto3.

Comment: Yes, it exists in the CloudWatch logs. I was able to find it by matching the timestamps.

Comment: Also are you sure that the job you are looking for is the first one `batch_response["jobs"][0]`? There are no other jobs [1] or [2]?

Comment: Edited the question with the `describe_jobs()` response. Could it be related to the boto3 release that happened today?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AWS Support has confirmed that there was an issue which prevented the `logStreamName` property from being populated in the AWS Batch DescribeJobs API, for jobs submitted between September 8, 10:42 AM and September 9, 4:07 PM PDT. They have resolved the issue.

Comment: can you share a ticket we can track? Because it still happens to my jobs right now

Comment: @lordvlad I raised the ticket with AWS Support via chat. Didn't raise it on a public forum so I am not sure if the ticket ID would be of any help.